# Struct field names starting with a string

Tags: go

I have a go struct and I need to work with one of the fields.  However I am starting with a string.  How do I case it to get the field itself.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {

    type Point struct{
  x int
  y int
}

    pt := Point{x:2, y:3}
    a  := "x"
    fmt.Printf("%s", pt.a)
}
```

Since `a = "x"` I am expecting `pt.x = 2`.  Here's the error message it prints out.  I am definitely starting with a string so I can't just remove the quotation marks.

```
$ go run point.go
# command-line-arguments
./point.go:14: pt.a undefined (type Point has no field or method a)
```

Comment: Is this `Point` struct your actual use case? Are you able to explain a little more about where you are trying to do this?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: The field names of `Point` are `x` and `y`, not `a`.

Comment: why doesn't it give `pt.x = 2` ?

Comment: string `"x"` has nothing to do with field `pt.x`

Comment: @Akavall how can I convert `"x"` into `x` ?  Python has `eval()` function so that `eval("2 + 3") = 5`

Comment: Write `pt.x` instead?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves  the string `"x"` is a URL parameter, and I would like to find data in a struct relating to `x`

Comment: Why not use `map` instead of `struct` then?

Comment: @Akavall perhaps `map` is more appropriate then... thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use reflection to use a dynamic field name for a struct field?

Comment: @benjic I solved it by switching to `map[string]int`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to access a field whose name is given as a string, you have no choice but to use reflection. Go ain't Python. :-)

[This blog](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) has a nice explanation.

[Here](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) is the reflect package documentation.

But note that reflection should usually be used as a last resort only. It removes the static type safety and is detrimental for performance.

What are you really looking for? There may be a way to address your requirements without using reflection. For example, if you don't need methods attached to your struct, you could use `map[string]int`.